# Creating block on player with name and enchantments

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to add a block on my head that has a name and some enchantments.
How can I do this with the `/replaceitem` command?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this many times make your command should look like this:

```
/replaceitem entity @a slot.armor.head minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:"Notch",display:{Name:"NAMEHERE"},ench:[{id:19,lvl:1}]}
```

Just change "id:19" with the id you want.